# How do I enable TCP MD5 Signatures on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

After a small amount of research it seems that [TCP MD5 Signatures](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2385.txt) are enabled on CentOS, but our PCI security software has indicated that our machines are not actually using it.  How do I configure CentOS to use TCP MD5 Signatures?

**Edit:**
I was thinking that this was a global setting, but it is actually a per-socket setting.  This means the application that is creating the socket (in this case Sun Application Server) has to be the one to specify this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP-MD5 is part of the Linux kernel; you will only have the capability if your kernel is compiled with the option enabled (you may be able to dump /proc/config.gz and if so, grep for CONFIG_TCP_MD5SIG) - the second part is an application that will actually perform the setsockopt() to enable TCP_MD5 for that connection.

Answer (score 0):

If CentOS is anything like RHEL, the kernel config should be under /boot.

```
grep TCP_MD5 /boot/config-*
```

Otherwise, yes, it's a somewhat undocumented option to setsockopt().

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps you are referring to [TCP SYN cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_cookies). To enable them:

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies
```

Comment: Looks like that particular option is already set since cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies returns 1.  I appreciate the effort though.